# How to get a specific peer status in asterisk

Tags: php, asterisk, asteriskami

Asterisk Call Manager/1.3 .After login I am able to retrieve all peer detail as a string.

```
fwrite($socket, "Action: Command\r\n");
fwrite($socket, "Command: sip show peer ".$sip_no."\r\n\r\n");
```

I need to know whether the channel is busy or not.

How Can I get only the status  like

```
function checkstatus(sip_no){
   .....
  return status;
}
```

Based on the status I need to do further processing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query the Asterisk manager and get a response for each of your peers, using the sip command, in your case, i.e.:

```
sip show peer PEERNAME
```

Where PEERNAME is the name of your peer.

Here's a page with an example script for this:

http://www.venturevoip.com/news.php?rssid=2217

Comment: Thanks.I searched a lot but didn't come across this document.let me play with this code.

Comment: note, use something like described is BAD BAD BAD idea. Asterisk can hangs if you use alot of such requests(bugs maybe?) correct solution - check AMI events and maintain info about channels, like asternic.org FOP panel do.

Comment: You're much better off using the actual AMI command that perform those functions, rather than using the CLI command over AMI approach. Exposing the command class authorization is generally not a good idea, as it gives the ability for any remotely connected client the ability to execute CLI commands on your system.

Peer Status: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerAction_SIPpeerstatus

Channels: https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+ManagerAction_CoreShowChannels